# How to handle No SuchElementException in python automation,

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("msgButtonAffirm")
if elem.is_displayed():
    elem.click()
    print("conform popup is avalable and click")
else:
    print "Pop-up is not visible"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_elements_by_id` and check if there is anything in the list

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("msgButtonAffirm")
if elem and elem[0].is_displayed():
    elem[0].click()
    print("conform popup is avalable and click")
else:
    print("Pop-up is not visible")
```

Comment: How can you be sure `elem[0]` contains the desired element you are looking out for? There can be multiple elements identified through `find_elements_by_id("msgButtonAffirm")` and the desired element can be `elem[2]`, `elem[3]` as well.

Comment: @DebanjanB `elem[0]` will contain the same element `find_element_by_id` will return.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was saying, so effectively, using `elem[0]` doesn't have any advantage over OP's `find_element_by_id()`

Comment: @DebanjanB The advantage is `find_elements_by_id` and `elem[0]` won't throw `NoSuchElementException`, which the OP receive if the popup doesn't appear, `find_element_by_id` will.

Comment: Only handling `NoSuchElementException` wouldn't solve the purpose (read as the usecase), rather I think we need the relevant HTML so the element can be uniquely identified first inducing WebDriverWait (if needed) and then proceed.

Comment: @DebanjanB I did read the question, the popup is not always there. Using `WebDriverWait` is a bad idea in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the exception and work with that as following:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("msgButtonAffirm")
    elem.click()
    print("conform popup is avalable and click")
except NoSuchElementException:  
    print("Pop-up is not visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- While clicking on *confirmation popups* you shouldn't major focus shouldn't be on handling `NoSuchElementException`
- Historically, in majority of the cases *confirmation popups* resides within *modal dialoge boxes* so you need to induce *WebDriverwait*.

The relevant HTML would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, as per the mentioned points, you need to to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#msgButtonAffirm"))).click()
      print ("Pop-up was clickable and clicked")
  except TimeoutException: 
      print ("Pop-up was not clickable")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='msgButtonAffirm']"))).click()
      print ("Pop-up was clickable and clicked")
  except TimeoutException: 
      print ("Pop-up was not clickable")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: And what if the popup will never appear? it will wait for 20 seconds for no reason.

Comment: @Guy The _timespan_ of **20** seconds is just an example here and can be set to any value e.g. **3**, **5**, **7**, **10**, etc. Effectively, the _timespan_ should be configured as per the _Test Plan_. The _Test Plan_ should define the _timeout_ duration for _Modal Dialog Box_, _Angular_ elements, _JavaScript_ based elements, etc.

Comment: The point is not how much time it waits, the point is it waits needlessly for a popup that might not be there.